# How to load data from file to code and use it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a login system in which first it will ask if you are registered or not. You can create new username or if you are existing then you can log in. My problem is that I save the data of username and password into a file. I want to load that usernames and passwords everytime I run my code, and log in to old users without creating any new one.

This is my code:

```
# global variable
users = {}
register = ''
valid = True
file = open('user_Info.txt', 'a')
# create a status if the user exist yes or no if yes old user is no new user
def registration():
    global register, valid, file
    register = input('if you are already registered enter y, n if you are a new user (enter x to exit): ')
    if register == 'y':
        old_User()
    elif register == 'n':
        new_User()
    else:
        register == 'x'
        valid = False
# Loading data into users global variable
def load_User():
    global users
    users = set(open('user_Info.txt', 'r'))

# new user
def new_User():
    global users, file
    username = input('creat username: ')
    file.write(username + ',')
    if username in users:
        print('username already exists!!!!!!')
    else:
        password = input('create a strong password: ')
        users[username] = password
        print('username created :)')
        file.write(password + ',\n')
# old user
def old_User():
    global users
    exist_Username = input('please enter your username: ')
    exist_Password = input('please enter your password: ')
    if exist_Username in users and users[exist_Username] == exist_Password:
        print('you have successfully logged in: ')
    else:
        print('Wrong username or password please try again')
def run():
    global valid, users
    load_User()
    while register != 'x':
        registration()
    file.close()
# execution code
run()
print(users)
```

Here I created files and save it, and using some sets to load the information but `\n` is printed. I don't know why. 
I also want to link the load data with username and password so I can use it in this code.

Comment: If you're new, you should spend extra time reading the instructions and site rules that are so emphasized with new questions. It will really help you get the help you need. As it stands, this question has some pretty severe issues, most of which could likely have been avoided by reading the instructions.

Comment: You can check my suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're doing a mistake here

```
def new_User():
global users, file
username = input('creat username: ')
file.write(username + ',') # you write the username before seeing if it exist
if username in users:
    print('username already exists!!!!!!')
else:
    password = input('create a strong password: ')
    users[username] = password
    print('username created :)')
    file.write(password + ',\n')
```

I can recommand you to do this instead :

```
def new_User():
global users, file
username = input('creat username: ')
if username in users:
    print('username already exists!!!!!!')
else: 
    password = input('create a strong password: ')        
    print('username created :)')
    file.write(username+' , '+password+'\n') # write username,password
```

About loading users , you load them on a list where each line of the file is an element ( user,password ) then you can either work with it like that or ( recommanded ) to create a class User which will have attributes username and password that you will use to create an object for each user , you can do it like this :

```
def load_users() :
    with open('user_Info.txt') as f:
    users_list = list(f) # each element is a string of username,password
```